# Dropdownlist Items retrieval issue on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListMySubjectz" runat="server">
                                              </asp:DropDownList>
```

I try to populate this in the CodeBehind in C#.

```
                                        HtmlGenericControl divMySubjects = (HtmlGenericControl)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("divMySubjects");
                    divMySubjects.Style["display"] = "block";
                    DropDownList mySubjects = (DropDownList)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("DropDownListMySubjectz");
                    UpdatePanel mySubjectsPanel = (UpdatePanel)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("UpdatePanelRequestAction");
                    mySubjects.DataSource = ProfileDataAccess.GetUserSubjects(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()).DefaultView;
                    mySubjects.DataTextField = "Subjects";
                    mySubjects.DataValueField = "SubjectId";
                    mySubjects.DataBind();
                    mySubjectsPanel.Update();
```

every thing works fine. Until the postback occurs. I try to get the items from the DRopDownList. But the DropDownlist is empty. However, there are value after populating it from codebehind. and it also get the same Dropdown intended.

```
 DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("DropDownListMySubjectz");


  DataSource that populate the gridview

 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceProfileSubjects" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetUserSubjects"
    TypeName="ProfileDataAccess">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenFieldUserId" Name="suserId" PropertyName="Value"
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: My guess is that your gridview is refreshing itself on every postback, and your databind method isn't being called. At what point in your code do you try to populate your drop down list?

Comment: I have a LinkButton When I click it its command event is called in which this code is executed. No GridView not refreshed. I have plenty of break points which are hit only on clicking.

Comment: Is your dropdown inside an update panel?  Is the postback to which you refer a full postback?

Comment: When/where are you populating your GridView?

Comment: Yes it is inside an updatepanel. No it is partial postback.

Comment: Just so I understand, the drop down populates the first time correctly, but after a postback your drop down values disappear? I think you'll need to save your data source into a ViewState object, and bind mySubjects.DataSource to it every time your grid refreshes.

Comment: Question Updated please review

Answer (score 0):

use ViewState. Enable page & control ViewState .
confirm it by

> IIS -> Your WebSite -> Pages & Controls -> Enable Viewstate & Enable
>   Sessionstate should be set to true.

or

load data to DropDownList in `OnInit` function then it should be loaded properly

Comment: The ViewState is not disabled anywhere not on page nor on DropDownList.

Comment: But the data is loaded I make selection from the items but when the LinkButton Command event is called it does not show any item.

Comment: @user1698985;yeah, this problem occurs mainly with dropdownlist

Comment: There must be a reason. I want to know why this happens so I can trace it in future.

Comment: @user1698985:OnInit takes place before Asp.Net loads values from the form into its objects. Page_Load takes place during the Load event, which occurs after the form is interrogated. Check out this page to learn about the page events in Asp.Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I know all this. But this does not relate to my problem. I have studied this here  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24611/ASP-NET-Internals-Viewstate-and-Page-Life-Cycle. Very detailed but I want to populate the dropdown when the user requests. Init makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have not installed the IIS.